# Asserting the params

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I want to assert the `params` but I have notice there is two way doing this:

`console.log(mockMethod.mock.calls[0][0])`

and

```
mockMethod.mockImplementationOnce((params, cb) => {
   console.log(params); //add assert here
   cb(null, {});
});
```

Both of them output the same result, which I should be using to assert (expect) the params object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic difference is that mock implement provides a mock implementation in which you just happened to be logging the parents. In the other, you are actually checking if the call was made with correct params. If you are looking to assert the params, then the first call is correct usage.